# Is it possible to find and filter records with one column that has matching values but unmatching values in another column?

Tags: text-processing, awk

I  need to filter out records in the second file:

Let's say the file1 is like so:

```
0006296 OIL FILTER PH3506   HONEYWELL   Parts and Repair    3101
0015735 OIL FILTER PH2870   HONEYWELL   Parts and Repair    3101
```

and file2 will be:

```
0006296 OIL FILTER PH3506   HONEYWELL   Parts and Repair    3101
0015735 OIL FILTER PH2870   HONEYWELL   Automotive          4201
```

how would I filter out the second row in file 2, based on the fact it has a matching first column but a column that doesn't match as in the last column.

Comment: Is there a 1:1 correspondence of lines in file 1 and file 2? That is to say, e.g., that line 2 is the same line in both files just with possibly different values in the last column? Or are there lines in file 1 not present in file 2, or vice-versa?

Comment: can you add more context (more lines) and expected result?

Comment: Kevin, both files will have the same number of columns. Roman, expected result would be to have the the first line only appear in the new file, as the second line shows a mismatch.

Comment: KevinO's question is whether the files have matching **lines**. How do you know that line 2 of file2 corresponds to line 1 of file1? Is it because of the line numbers, or because one of the columns (which one) has the same content? What do you do when a line in file2 doesn't match any of the lines in file1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be enough using as key the first and the last field:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1"-"$NF]++;next}$1"-"$NF in a' file1 file2
0006296 OIL FILTER PH3506   HONEYWELL   Parts and Repair    3101
```

We are separating those two fields with something (a dash in my example) to avoid confusion of `0006296 and 3101` with  `00062963 and 101`